# jQuery.hover not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, hover

This javascript works fine in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE8:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
     $("#button").button();
     $("#radioset").buttonset();

     $('#ciao,#dialog_link, ul#icons li ').hover(
       function() { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover ui-corner-left '); }, 
       function() { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover ');}
     ); 
   });
</script>
```

And this html:

```
    <a href="http://www.myhome">
   <label id="ciao" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-left ui-corner-right ui-state-active" >
   <span id="ciao" class="ui-button-text ui-corner-left ui-corner-right">Home page</span></label></a>
   </a>

   <a href="register.php">
   <label id="ciao" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-left ui-corner-right ui-state-active" >
   <span id="ciao" class="ui-button-text ui-corner-left ui-corner-right">Put your logo!</span></label></img>
   </a>

   <a href="faqs.html">
   <label id="ciao" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-left ui-corner-right ui-state-active" >
   <span id="ciao" class="ui-button-text ui-corner-left ui-corner-right">FAQs</span></label></img>
   </a>

   <a href="logos.html">
   <label id="ciao" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-left ui-corner-right ui-state-active" >
   <span id="ciao" class="ui-button-text ui-corner-left ui-corner-right">Logos</span></label></img>
   </a>

   <a href="contact.html">
   <label id="ciao" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-left ui-corner-right ui-state-active" >
   <span id="ciao" class="ui-button-text ui-corner-left ui-corner-right">Contact us</span></label>
   </a>
```

Why it is not working in IE8??

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're re-using IDs, and they should be unique, change your elements to use `class="caio"` instead, and change your selector from `#caio` to `.caio`, like this:

```
$(function(){ 
  $("#button").button(); 
  $("#radioset").buttonset();
  $('.ciao, #dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(function() { 
    $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover ui-corner-left '); 
  }, function() { 
    $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover ');
  });
});
```

Comment: Ok now the hover function work. but if I click on a button it doesn't work....the browser don't go to the page linked. In Firefox work.

Answer (score -2):

```
<label onClick="document.location.href='http://en.theitalianbrand.com/contact.html';" class="ciao ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-left ui-corner-right ui-state-active" >
<span class="ciao ui-button-text ui-corner-left ui-corner-right">Contact us</span></label>
```